# does wp7 isolatedstoragesettings.save rewrites the whole data again

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am developing an app for wp7.I am using Isolatedstoragesettings to save my data.

I want to know does IsolatedStorageSettings.save() incrementally saves the data
or does it entirely rewrites the data i.e data which is already stored is again rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

It will rewrite the entire dictionary out again.